# Access web site by location in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urlopen

Some web site have a `pt.`, `en.` in the beginner or `.br`, `.it` at the end because of the server location.

When I use the library of python as the function `urlopen` I have to pass the full adress string of the web site, including the termination string of the server location (for international servers).

Some international web sites have the each country service. There some way to python make this transparent to the user? (adding the termination or starter string) Because some webpage to not redirect to the local proximity server in an automatic way.

Comment: If you try to access google.com and google decides to forward you automatically to google.se (for example), there's nothing the client can do about it - whether that client is a human or a python script. That is controlled by the webserver, not the client.

Comment: We have some kind of issue with some users of one python library that access the price of product. Sometimes, Europe user got the response of USA (USD dolar e not Euro) user.

Comment: If the server decides for you, then you're stuck, unless you use a VPN to make yourself appear to be from a different county. Maybe the server allows you set your preference for currency?

Comment: You should try to use an API instead of accessing interactive websites.

Comment: Yes, when you access with the browser with the "wrong" locatation termination string, it ask if you prefer change or not. I you check better with the development team. Thanks @DanielleM.

Comment: I got some interesting results adding 'en-US' or others in my `req.add_header('Accept-Language', 'en-US')` to after `urlopen(req)`. Do you now how can I get this 'en-US' definition string by internet/OS resource?

Comment: @hildogjr Here’s the complete list of the language tags https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/language-codes/latest/data/csv/data/ietf-language-tags.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you try to access google.com and google decides to forward you
>   automatically to google.se (for example), there's nothing the client
>   can do about it - whether that client is a human or a python script.
>   That is controlled by the webserver, not the client.

What Danielle said in the comment is not entirely correct, when the client access the webpage "google.com", the site host noticed your ip location and send back a signal telling the browser to redirect the current site to "google.se" (To go with Danielle's example) to make the site match your ip location. However, you can avoid redirects. As for the sake of the question, here's a simple demonstration using python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library. Setting `allow_redirects` to `False`.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
print(r.url)
# 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=mpewWZGdGePs8we597n4Dw'
# requests automatically followed the redirect link to google.ca

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', allow_redirects=False)
print(r.url)

# 'https://www.google.com/'
# here it says at google.com
```

Your question isn't clear enough to provide a more thorough answer. But I hope my example has helped you a bit.